# geometric construct in GeoRegionValuePlot doesn't work?

Tags: plotting, version-10

As stated in the documentation of `GeoRegionValuePlot`:

> The *reg* can be Entity objects such as countries corresponding to extended geographic regions, or geometric constructs with GeoPosition coordinates.

However, the code as follows doesn't work:

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[{GeoDisk[GeoPosition[{48, 5}], 100000] -> 3.4, GeoDisk[GeoPosition[{49, 6}], 200000] -> 5.4}, Frame -> True]
```

result:
[image]

Obviously, *Mathematica* recognized the GeoDisk as a GeoPosition rather than a geometric construct.

Is this a bug? Or is there anything I happened to miss?

Comment: This has been fixed in V10.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you state in the comment section, this has been fixed with the version 10.0.1.

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[{GeoDisk[GeoPosition[{48, 5}], 100000] -> 3.4, 
  GeoDisk[GeoPosition[{49, 6}], 200000] -> 5.4}, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did not appreciate the aim of the question and look forward to answers. I post this as, perhaps, a way to get to. The labelling here is just the opacities but could be adapted. I could not find support for an annular region hence this approach. I am sure there are better more creative ways.

```
gg = GeoGraphics[{{Opacity[0.2], Red, 
    GeoDisk[GeoPosition[{48, 5}], 100000]}, Opacity[0.2], Red, 
   GeoDisk[GeoPosition[{48, 5}], 200000], {Opacity[0.2], Red, 
    GeoDisk[GeoPosition[{48, 5}], 300000]}}];
leg = GraphicsColumn[
  Table[Graphics[{{, Opacity[j], Red, Rectangle[]}, 
     Text[Style[j, 12], Center]}], {j, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2}], Spacings -> 0,
   ImageSize -> 40];
Legended[gg, leg]
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL POST**

I may have missed your point. I am uncertain what the aim of 3.4 is. The `GeoGraphics` may be what you want. I accept I may have misunderstood. For example, 5 km "circle" around your position.

```
Manipulate[
 GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["ReliefImage"], Red, Thick, 
   GeoCircle[GeoPosition[{48, 5}], 5000], 
   GeoMarker[GeoPosition[{48, 5}]], 
   GeoMarker[GeoPosition[{48, long}]]}, GeoRangePadding -> 500, 
  Frame -> True], {long, 5.01, 5.07}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi ubpdqn, 3.4 refers to a value that should be interpreted to a certain color. GeoGraphics does plot the geometric construct properly, however, GeoRegionValuePlot doesn't. Thanks for your help but GeoGraphics is not what I need. I also updated the description of the question a little bit to show the purpose of using GeoRegionValuePlot

Comment: @sunt05 sorry...from the documentation of `GeoRegionValuePlot` I interpreted regions to refer to geographic/political regions which can be colored (scale) by curated data or user-defined values. Apart from a table that presents grid points explicitly constructed I could no find geometric regions. Hence, my recourse to `GeoGraphics` as an option you may be able to customize to your needs. I appreciate my answer does not respond to your direct question.